# How to select columns that contain specific values of a chosen row in R?

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
Site <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"kingdom","phylum","class")
A <- c(0,0,1,2,4,5,6,7,13,56,"Eukaryota","Arthropoda","Insecta")
B <- c(1,0,0,0,0,4,5,7,7,8,"Eukaryota","Arthropoda","Insecta")
C <- c(2,3,0,0,4,5,67,8,43,21,"Eukaryota","Arthropoda","")
D <- c(134,0,0,2,0,0,9,0,45,55,"Eukaryota","Arthropoda","Arachnida")
site.species.sample <- data.frame(Site,A,B,C,D)
```

I want to select only the columns from this dataset where the row "class" is "Insecta" (i.e. in this example only columns A and B satisfy this condition). I tried this code:

```
site.species.sample <- site.species.sample[,site.species.sample["class",]=="Insecta"]
```

But got an error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(site.species.sample, , site.species.sample["class",  : 
undefined columns selected
```

So how do I do it? Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you keep character and numeric data in the same column?

Comment: yes, that's the format of my dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an option

```
site.species.sample[,c(TRUE,subset(site.species.sample[,-1],site.species.sample$Site=="class")=="Insecta")]

Site          A          B
1        1          0          1
2        2          0          0
3        3          1          0
4        4          2          0
5        5          4          0
6        6          5          4
7        7          6          5
8        8          7          7
9        9         13          7
10      10         56          8
11 kingdom  Eukaryota  Eukaryota
12  phylum Arthropoda Arthropoda
13   class    Insecta    Insecta
```

Comment: can I ask what does the [,-1] mean? Thanks

Comment: It excludes the first column from subsetting to ensure it will be selected in any case. Then with `c(TRUE,` inserts `TRUE` as first element of vector to select first column.

Comment: By any chance, do you know why did my original code not work? What's wrong with the command? Thanks

Comment: `site.species.sample["class",]` This part gives error because there is no column with the name `class`